# Markov Chain Property and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Hey everyone I have a question about deconstructing this conditional probability. After using Bayes Rule and then attempting to use $P(A | B,C) = P(A,B | B,C)$ and $P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(A,B | C)}{P(B|C)}$ I can not for the life of me figure out how to make both sides equal.

See this [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtaNJ.png)

Thank You

P.S. First time poster so hopefully everything is ok with question, tried searching prior to asking. $($Already asked this on wrong forum $-1$ for me$)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(.|C)$ is a Probability function itself. So

$$P(A|B,C)=\frac{P(A,B|C)}{P(B|C)}$$
Just like
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$$

For the second question, Analogously, it's only the Total Probability Theorem. Just Like

$$P(A)=P(A,B)+P(A,B^c)$$

Comment: Ah I see I didn't think you could expand the Total Probability Theorem in that way. Thank you so much for the edit and explanation. Mersi

Comment: @user415853 Your welcome... Mersi with "S"?! It's somehow weird!

Comment: Merci* it's been a long math-filled night aha thanks again